# What is the difference between exporting library paths to LD_LIBRARY_PATH and using the -L flags while linking?

Tags: c, linker, shared-libraries

To further explain my situation. I know that when you're using dynamic libraries, you need to export the library paths to LD_LIBRARY_PATH, so that the executable will find the libraries when they're run. If I don't do this, an error will come up, that the shared library could not be found.

Now if I add the following linker flag "-L/path/to/library/ -lthelibrary.so", I can run my executable without exporting the library path to LD_LIBRARY_PATH.

Why is this?

Comment: Good Read: [Why LD_LIBRARY_PATH is bad?](http://xahlee.info/UnixResource_dir/_/ldpath.html)

Comment: Hmm, as far as I know there isn't any way to embed actual search paths besides the "rpath" entry in the executable, but for that, LD_RUN_PATH would have to be set (not LD_LIBRARY_PATH). Does the path show up when you run "readelf <program> -d"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, you do not generally *need* to set `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` to run a binary. This environment variable is used by the loader to find *additional* places to look for `.so` files to load when the binary is to be executed.

You *need* to set `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` if your binary references one or more `.so` files that are not available in the same location as when it was compiled. It is also needed if any of the directly referenced `.so` files depend on something that is not available in the same as when the `.so` file was created.

Use the `ldd` command to inspect the dependency information in your binary to get a clearer picture of what is saved by the linker when the binary is created.

Comment: Ok, the ldd command was very helpful. It is only one library that the binary doesn't seem to find without the help of LD_LIBRARY_PATH. The library is still in the same location when the binary was built. What could be the cause of this?

Comment: By the way, this one library is libiniparser.so.0, the others end with .so. Do I have to make a symbolic libiniparser.so link and does this have to be in the same directory as libiniparser.so.0?

Comment: Ok, that was the answer. Works now!

Comment: @schwalbs Glad I could help and that you solved the remaining issue.